# Can't hear any music in Psychonauts (Humble Indie Bundle V)

Tags: sound, games

I bought Humble Indie Bundle V and Psychonauts has no music. I mean, I can hear the sound effects and the characters' voices, but there is no music in any of the levels where I know it should be playing.

I've tried changing the setting in the Audio menu but that didn't work... I installed the graphics drivers for my ATI Radeon HD 4830 through the Additional drivers menu and also the landscape sometimes seems to be flickering whenever I am outside (only the grass).

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: This is a bug: https://bugzilla.icculus.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5569 and Ryan (the guy who ported the game) says it will be fixed in the next patch (0.5).

Comment: And the fixing patch has now been released. Available from http://treefort.icculus.org/psychonauts/ and probably as an update through the repositories at some point.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to download the patch 0.4 and extract it to the Psychonauts folder from this [link](http://treefort.icculus.org/psychonauts/).
I have some bug and with this patch i solved.

PS: The psychonaut folder is in /opt/Psychonauts if you installed it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: No, that didn't help, I still can't hear any music.